# When to use at symbol to reference an instance variable and when not to?

Tags: ruby

If I have a custom class with a method that prints the instance variable `var` should I reference `var` using an `at symbol @`?

TL;DR: should I use the method `puts_reader` or `puts_ivar` and why?

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :var

  def initialize
    @var = "foobar"
  end

  def puts_reader
    puts var
  end

  def puts_ivar
    puts @var
  end
end
```

Comment: instance variable is *always* referenced with `@`, local variable without `@`. `attr_reader` just adds an instance ***method*** `var` for you, so it is neither instance variable nor local one.

Comment: Slightly dubious use of TL;DR here:)

Comment: As you have shown already, you can reference `@var` with either `@var` or `var` (providing you have the wrapper method setup). It's up to you, @var is marginally faster but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you can use just `var` because the `attr_reader` that is something like

```
def var
  @var
end
```

Comment: Oh, so var uses the implicit method `var` because of `attr_reader :var`?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)